# Save button and TOC layers missing from Portal Web Map (ArcGIS Enterprise)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, web-service, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I have a few web maps in portal that correctly show data without any errors but there are no layers shown in the TOC (Contents) and the Save button is missing.

This sometimes happens when I update a service, more specifically, delete a service and publish a service of the same name (using Pro "Map Image Service" (cached) since these cannot be simply overwritten as vector services can)

If I remove the layer for that particular service from the web map prior to deleting it, then re-creating it, then add to the map, everything works fine. If I don't do that the TOC (Contents) no longer shows layers and the save button is gone. If I search for layers in this (now broken) web map, it still works and if I add a new item, the TOC layers mysteriously appear! However, since the Save button is gone, I can't repair and update my web map by simply saving it.

When I use the the [ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/) to repair any broken links it doesn't really do anything since the links are valid and are actually identical to what they were before. Furthermore, the new "updated" service correctly appears in the web map, just the TOC has no layers and the Save button is missing.

I should add that I am the admin and have all admin privileges. I looked online for some answers but only found [one post on GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/183862-the-save-button-is-missing-on-my-portal-map) but none of the suggestions there offer any solutions or workaround.

How Can I bring back the Save button?

Example of a "broken" web map (TOC layers missing and no save button):
[image]

Example of a correct web map (TOC layers and button shown):
[image]

Comment: If you open client logs (F12) and refresh page, anything weird in console or failed requests in the network tab?

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue. Was there a result from the original post?